# Beeline cannot connect to HiveServe2 with NOSASL authentication mode ( old client )

Tags: hadoop, authentication, hive, beeline

This question is common here, there are several flavors of it. In this scenario, I set up an HiveServer2 with no authentication ( NOSASL ) which is working from Python, where I'm using Impyla library to connect.
When I connect using beeline, there is no way to get a working connection.

Beeline ends with:

```
 beeline> !connect jdbc:hive2://127.0.0.1:10000/default/hive
 Error: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://127.0.0.1:10000/default/hive: null (state=08S01,code=0)
```

In HiveServer2 logs I have:

```
17/11/16 20:59:35 [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-34]: ERROR server.TThreadPoolServer: Thrift error occurred during processing of message.
org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocolException: Missing version in readMessageBegin, old client?
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:228)
    at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:27)
    at org.apache.hive.service.auth.TSetIpAddressProcessor.process(TSetIpAddressProcessor.java:56)
    at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:285)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Finally, I found the solution.

```
!connect jdbc:hive2://127.0.0.1:10000/default/;auth=noSasl
```

Using this I'm able to connect to HiveServer2.
Also, I'm using HiveServer2 for development, so I started the processes under root and all the file system tree belongs to root. Due to this option, I need to use the root user when login to HiveServer2 using beeline:

```
Connecting to jdbc:hive2://127.0.0.1:10000/default/;auth=noSasl
Enter username for jdbc:hive2://127.0.0.1:10000/default/;auth=noSasl: root
Enter password for jdbc:hive2://127.0.0.1:10000/default/;auth=noSasl: 
Connected to: Apache Hive (version 1.2.2)
```

I did not need to provide the password since there is no authentication at all. Now I'm able to create databases and tables.

This "[​Comparing Beeline to the Hive CLI](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.2/bk_dataintegration/content/beeline-vs-hive-cli.html)" has been a valid reference to solve this problem.

Comment: Oddly my EMR hive setup fails unless there is no auth session variable provided or the variable is set to blank or "NONE" or "none".

Comment: Which versions of software are you using ?

Comment: I'm using EMR 5.16 and 5.18; yet to try 5.19. They come with Hive 2.3.3 The client I was using though was saying thrift hive protocol 2.1 was in use, so maybe something around that.